# Pyramid i18n use two locale directories

Tags: python, internationalization, pyramid, jinja2

How to use locale directory from include package and locale directory in my own project.

My main function

```python
settings = dict(settings)
settings.setdefault('jinja2.i18n.domain', 'mypackage1, mypackage2') #NOT WORK!!!

config.include("mypackage1")
config.add_jinja2_search_path(("mypackage1:templates",
                               "mypackage2:templates"))

config.add_translation_dirs("mypackage1:locale/",
                            "mypackage2:locale/")
config.add_jinja2_search_path(("mypackage1:templates",
                               "mypackage2:templates"))

return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have misunderstood what the context it. To quote the pyramid glossary :

> A string representing the “context” in which a translation was made.
>   For example the word “java” might be translated differently if the
>   translation domain is “programming-languages” than would be if the
>   translation domain was “coffee”. A translation domain is represnted by
>   a collection of .mo files within one or more translation directory
>   directories.

It's not possible to cumulate contexts by setting it to something like 'mypackage1, mypackage2'. What you need to do is make sure that all translation dirs have the same domain, set it in the configuration and call `add_translation_dirs` with the multiple dirs.